# Cannot get any results with Net::SSLeay for openssl

Tags: perl, ssl, openssl, x509

I am trying to create a script that looks at the data for my certs in my ~/ssl/certs folder and displays the issuer information to me.

It's written in perl and it would be easy to just say:

```
$data = `/usr/bin/openssl x509 -in $file -noout -issuer`
```

However that is not very portable. I am trying to use Net::SSLeay instead to get the same output, however all I can seem to manage are checksum numbers, what am I missing? Here is what I got

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.10.1;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SSLeay qw(die_now die_if_ssl_error);
Net::SSLeay::load_error_strings();
Net::SSLeay::SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms();    # Important!
Net::SSLeay::ENGINE_load_builtin_engines();  # If you want built-in engines
Net::SSLeay::ENGINE_register_all_complete(); # If you want built-in engines
Net::SSLeay::randomize();
Net::SSLeay::library_init();
Net::SSLeay::OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
my $file = '~/ssl/certs/certificate.crt';

my $x509 = Net::SSLeay::X509_new(); 
Net::SSLeay::X509_free($x509);
my $type = Net::SSLeay::X509_certificate_type($x509);
my $ctx = Net::SSLeay::CTX_new_with_method(Net::SSLeay::TLSv1_method());
my $test = Net::SSLeay::X509_load_cert_file( $ctx, $file, $type );
my $info = Net::SSLeay::X509_issuer_name_hash($x509);

say "\nInfo = $info \nX509 = $x509\nTest= $test\nType = $type\nCTX = $ctx";



This is my output:
Info = 4003674586 
X509 = 16119648
Test= 0
Type = 0
CTX = 16137888
```

I've read through all the source code and the documentation, none of it makes any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need all this context etc. After you've initialized the SSL library you can simply do:

```
my $bio = Net::SSLeay::BIO_new_file($file,'r') or die $!;
my $cert = Net::SSLeay::PEM_read_bio_X509($bio);
Net::SSLeay::BIO_free($bio);
$cert or die "cannot parse $file as PEM X509 cert: ".
    Net::SSLeay::ERR_error_string(Net::SSLeay::ERR_get_error());
my $issuer = Net::SSLeay::X509_NAME_oneline(
    Net::SSLeay::X509_get_issuer_name($cert));
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! That worked perfectly, they really need to explain their documentation better.

Comment: @Jeffrey: `Net::SSLeay` is free software and the maintainers are in my experience very open for changes which improve the software. So feel free to provide the patches which make the documentation better.

Comment: Is it possible to decode the base64 version of the certifcate or key entirely and print the data? It seems that you can only print the subject, issuer, and very few other things. I am trying to compare the modulus on the key and cert to make sure they match

Comment: Looking at the source code of OpenSSL apps/x509.c  I would say that the modulus is only available by accessing internal structures and not with an API function. So you probably will not get it with a Net::SSLeay function.

Answer (score 0):

This example may be able to get you started:

https://metacpan.org/source/MIKEM/Net-SSLeay-1.68/examples/x509_cert_details.pl

I've snipped the relevant bits from it to just get the issuer:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::SSLeay qw/XN_FLAG_RFC2253 ASN1_STRFLGS_ESC_MSB/;

Net::SSLeay::randomize();
Net::SSLeay::load_error_strings();
Net::SSLeay::ERR_load_crypto_strings();
Net::SSLeay::SSLeay_add_ssl_algorithms();

my $file = shift;
chomp($file);

my $bio = Net::SSLeay::BIO_new_file($file, 'rb') or die "ERROR: BIO_new_file failed";
my $x509 = Net::SSLeay::PEM_read_bio_X509($bio) or die "ERROR: PEM_read_bio_X509 failed";

my $issuer_name = Net::SSLeay::X509_get_issuer_name($x509);
print Net::SSLeay::X509_NAME_print_ex($issuer_name) . "\n";
```

So then:

```
$ perl ssl.pl /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/XRamp_Global_CA_Root.crt
CN=XRamp Global Certification Authority,O=XRamp Security Services Inc,OU=www.xrampsecurity.com,C=US
```